# OauthPrompt is not working inside of teams, works fine in emulator and in 'Test in Web chat'

Tags: azure-web-app-service, botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

We are trying to authenticate users with Azure AD V2 so we can use their tokens to make API calls to graph API. We are following the sample number 46 in https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/46.teams-auth.

OauthPrompt is not working inside of Teams, works fine in Bot Framework Emulator and in 'Test in Web chat'. Inside of Teams app and in Teams' web app, the bot does not prompt the user with a sign-in button.

Comment: First check what error you are getting in the teams ?

Comment: As per previous commenter, please provide any error details. One thing to possibly look for though is the make sure your bot's App Id and App Password are correctly captured in your configuration

Comment: Do you have a dev environment to play with? If so, try to use a visual studio feature called "remote debug" and see the OnEventAdded method from your main bot. Webchat and emulator uses a form of credentials, while msteams uses another one sightly different.

Comment: @RajeeshMenoth there are no errors, the prompt just does not render in teams. I have added more context here: https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/issues/3872
I am unsure if this is an actual bug, but I think it could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow this [Add authentication to your Teams bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/add-authentication?tabs=dotnet%2Cdotnet-sample).

Important steps to keep in mind while following the doc:

1. [Create the Azure AD identity provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp%2Caadv2#create-the-azure-ad-identity-provider)
2. [Register the Azure AD v2 identity provider with the bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp%2Caadv2#register-the-azure-ad-identity-provider-with-the-bot).

Comment: Following the doc does help. What I was missing was that I had to create a new Azure AD app registration other than the one that was created by default when I created the bot. I then had to use the new registration's id for the connection client id.